# Statistics on migration from SO to mSO

Tags: support, closed-questions, deleted-questions, statistics, migrated-questions

I have some data to look at now thanks to the [new 10k question close statistics tool!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257449/new-10k-tool-question-close-statistics). However, there is some nuance that I am curious about with regards to migrating questions from SO to mSO which is not evident in the current statistics. The tool takes a little bit of time to load so I will stick with just the 30 day time frame for my numbers here.

In the past 30 days, 264796 questions were asked, 27447 questions were closed, and 264 questions were migrated from Stack Overflow. In other words, 1 out of every 1,000 questions is migrated. Perhaps migration closure is useful only to save time for moderators from handling flags, which is still a valid reason to retain it. However, I would like some extra statistics for the questions which are migrated to meta Stack Overflow.

It seems that "meta" questions posted accidentally or not on Stack Overflow are almost always closed quickly when they arrive here, and are often rather hostile or deeply off topic. Here is a recent example of one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298257/why-is-this-site-such-assholes-to-beginners . It was deleted very quickly from flags which was nice. Here is an image for those of you not 10k. It is kind of inflammatory so I placed it inside of a "spoiler" (you have to mouse over to see it).

> [image]

The question above may have been handled quickly, but it seems that most of the time these types of inflammatory posts are being migrated to meta when there is some sort of gripe or annoyance with an aspect of the main site as opposed to just simply closing them or even flagging them directly on the main site.

To me it seems that these questions are almost always immediately closed upon arrival but I have no way to actually determine that.

tmd;dr; What percent of questions migrated from Stack Overflow to meta Stack Overflow are closed or deleted?

Comment: I enjoy how you tried to shield the eyes of the delicate by putting the screenshot in spoiler tags, but left the incoherent profanity clearly readable in the link above.

Comment: @MarkAmery - The image was a lot more glaring and in your face than seeing the word in a link ;) Nothing like a big bold `<h1>` to really take over a post. Moreover, this post wasn't really about this one question, but more about the pattern of that type of question. Also, users here are pretty tough, I don't think that one word really bothered anyone.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As a 10k user, I think you should have access to the same close vote statistics on Meta. In particular, [the "migrated" tab on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=migrated&daterange=last2days) should answer some of your question. Unfortunately, you can't see deleted posts.

Counting deleted posts, in the last 30 days, 31 questions have been migrated from SO to Meta.SO. Of those, 10 have been deleted. 16 of the 31 were closed, with closing as a duplicate the most common reason.

I should note that some of these stats were skewed a bit in this interval by a certain user who created multiple accounts to complain about another user on SO, with many of those questions being migrated here and closed / deleted.

Comment: "you can't see deleted posts" - you can. That's 10k tools.